# cmd vel - control robot

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I have a problem using ROS. I'm a beginner. I want to move [this robot](https://github.com/BruceChanJianLe/p3dx) in the Gazebo simulation.

What I'm doing is the following:
I open a terminal and type:

`roscore`

Then I open a new tab and I type:

`cd catkin_ws`

`roslaunch p3dx_gazebo p3dx_empty_world.launch`

So Gazebo opens with the robot inside.

Now I want to move the robot (send  command via `cmd_vel` topic).
What I'm doing here is this:

`rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 10 -- '[2.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'`

But the robot doesn't move.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401790/cmd-vel---control-robot/) by [NickRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/56714/nickros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-06-02**:
Check if Simulation is not paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check your topics using `rostopic list`. By default your robot launches with the namespace `pioneer` according to [this line](https://github.com/BruceChanJianLe/p3dx/blob/874add6b4adaca0026ac8a90d175dd06d11902d2/p3dx_gazebo/launch/p3dx_empty_world.launch#L6). I'm guessing your `cmd_vel` topic is actually called `/pioneer/cmd_vel` in that case publishing to `cmd_vel` isn't going to do anything.

If you do not want to use a namespace, you need to launch `roslaunch p3dx_gazebo p3dx_empty_world_no_ns.launch`.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-06-02**:
nice catch!